# Have to load view matrix twice. Don't know why

Tags: c, opengl

This is the weirdest bug i have ever encountered. My triangle will not be drawn unless I Load the view matrix twice. What is going on?

If i remove one of the gfxSetCamera(&camera->t); nothing is drawn.

```
void shipDraw() {
 glPushMatrix();

 glMultMatrixf(ship->t.m);

 glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
 glColor3f(0,0,1);
 glVertex3f(0, 0, -1);  
 glVertex3f(0, 1, 1);
 glVertex3f(0, -1, 1);
 glEnd();

 glPopMatrix(); 
}

//Draw loop
 while(!gfxUserQuit()) {  
  entUpdateAll(); 

  gfxPrepare(1,1);

  gfxSetCamera(&camera->t); //Have to call this twice!?!?
  gfxSetCamera(&camera->t);

  entDrawAll(); 
  gfxPresent();
 }

//Graphics code
void gfxPrepare(int clearColor, int clearStencil) {
 //TODO parse args
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
 glLoadIdentity();
}

void gfxPresent() {
 glfwSwapBuffers();
}

void gfxSetCamera(transform *t) { 
 float *m = t->m;

 float viewmatrix[16]={
  m[0], m[4], m[8], 0,
  m[1], m[5], m[9], 0,
  m[2], m[6], m[10], 0,

  -(m[0]*m[12] +
  m[1]*m[13] +
  m[2]*m[14]),

  -(m[4]*m[12] +
  m[5]*m[13] +
  m[6]*m[14]),

  -(m[8]*m[12] +
  m[9]*m[13] +
  m[10]*m[14]), 1};
 glLoadMatrixf(viewmatrix);
}
```

**EDIT: I have reduced the error down to the following**

```
while(!gfxUserQuit()) {     
        entUpdateAll(); 

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        float *m = camera->t.m;
        float viewmatrix[16]={
            m[0], m[4], m[8], 0,
            m[1], m[5], m[9], 0,
            m[2], m[6], m[10], 0,

            -(m[0]*m[12] +
            m[1]*m[13] +
            m[2]*m[14]),

            -(m[4]*m[12] +
            m[5]*m[13] +
            m[6]*m[14]),

            -(m[8]*m[12] +
            m[9]*m[13] +
            m[10]*m[14]), 1}; 

        float viewmatrix2[16]={
            m[0], m[4], m[8], 0,
            m[1], m[5], m[9], 0,
            m[2], m[6], m[10], 0,

            -(m[0]*m[12] +
            m[1]*m[13] +
            m[2]*m[14]),

            -(m[4]*m[12] +
            m[5]*m[13] +
            m[6]*m[14]),

            -(m[8]*m[12] +
            m[9]*m[13] +
            m[10]*m[14]), 1};

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glLoadMatrixf(viewmatrix2);

        entDrawAll();   
        glfwSwapBuffers();
    }
```

If i remove the definition and initialization of 'float viewmatrix' nothing is draw to screen. If i restore it it renders as normal. Is this some memory corruption or something?

**EDIT2 they are different.**

How can i debug this?
[image]

**EDIT3** I was calling glfwGetTime() without including the file. This is what was breaking it :O

Comment: try memory break-points to debug that!

Comment: Is the thing that camera->t.m points to definitely at least 15 floats?

Comment: yep its 16 floats. 4x4 matrix

Answer (score 0):

What if, from your second example, you replaced "float viewmatrix...;" with "char tmpbuffer[16 * sizeof(float);" and then (assuming that did nothing) added "memset(tmpbuffer, 0, sizeof(tmpbuffer));"?

It sounds like something is corrupting your stack and that the first viewmatrix definition "fixes" it for the second one. What I'm suggesting should verify the problem is something along this line.

Comment: It was caused by calling a glfw function without importing the header file in the file that was calling it. leading to some memory corruption